# Compute mean and remove outliers from data divided by hours in r

Tags: r, aggregate, average, outliers

[part of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A65nm.jpg)I'm trying to compute the average of hourly measurements (about 20 per hour) from a large data set (4 months of data), but I need to remove the outliers per hour having the definition of being 2SD away from the hourly mean.

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), MONTH = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), DAY = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HOUR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), MINUTE = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), SECOND = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tmp = c(25.6984, 25.6967, 25.6962, 25.6962, 
25.6955, 25.6949, 25.6959, 25.6944, 25.6954, 25.6954, 25.6958, 
25.6958, 25.6962, 25.6967, 25.6982, 25.6976, 25.6978, 25.6977, 
25.6975, 25.6979, 25.5552, 25.5577, 25.5579, 25.5573, 25.746, 
25.7248, 25.7164, 25.7249, 25.7379, 25.752, 25.7502, 25.7678, 
25.7805, 25.7871, 25.7863, 25.7856, 25.7948, 25.7939, 25.7953, 
25.7969, 25.7982, 25.7981, 25.7972, 25.7978, 25.644, 25.6451, 
25.6455, 25.6456, 25.6451, 25.6454)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable and clear logic, but we need some data in order to help you.

Comment: I add a picture of part of data. As you can see, I have columns separated by month, day and minutes.

Comment: Not very helpful as I have to type the data myself. :) Can you use `dput()` and post the output here? Look how it looks for the first 3 rows of `mtcars`: `dput(mtcars[1:3,])`

Comment: Is it better? It´s only part of data, I have more columns...

Comment: The part of data you posted don't have enough variation, so I'm manually changing a value to create an outlier. Hope my answer helps...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the data you posted as `df`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# manually changing first value to create an outlier
df$Tmp[1] = 60

df %>%
  group_by(HOUR) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(Tmp),
         SD = sd(Tmp),
         IsOutlier = ifelse(Tmp < MEAN-2*SD | Tmp > MEAN+2*SD, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 50 x 10
#    YEAR MONTH   DAY  HOUR MINUTE SECOND   Tmp  MEAN    SD IsOutlier
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  2018     1     1     0      1      0  60    27.4  7.67         1
# 2  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# 3  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# 4  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# 5  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# 6  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# 7  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# 8  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# 9  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
#10  2018     1     1     0      1      0  25.7  27.4  7.67         0
# # ... with 40 more rows
```

You can see that the first row is classified as an outlier row, which you can remove using `... %>% filter(IsOutlier == 0)` at a later stage.

I left the columns I've created in order to see how the process works.

Comment: It worked! But how do I transform into a new dataframe? The second part (to remove the outlier) is also uncleared...

Comment: Answer mentions using `filter`.

Comment: You can save that whole process as df2 (your new data frame). You can add that last part in the end of the process of you want to filter out the outliers.

Comment: Yes! I needed to make small changes (creating a column with decimal data), but it worked pretty well, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `ave` (from built-in `stats` library for inline aggregation) to calculate *outlier*:

```
df$outlier <- ave(df$Tmp, df$HOUR, 
                  FUN=function(x) (x < (mean(x) - sd(x)*2)) | (x > (mean(x) + sd(x)*2)))
```

And then subset accordingly:

```
subdf <- subset(df, outlier == 0)
```